# Forgot Password Issue in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using jv_excali template for my application based on joomla 1.5.26. I am using the default login module.

But whenever I am trying to reset my password, I am not getting the expected result. Whenever I copy and paste the token id,getting through mail, I am getting "Your password reset confirmation failed because the token was invalid.."

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

**Navigate** to this:`template_name/html/com_user/reset/confirm.php`

Just add this code per the description in the link:

```
<tr> 
  <td height="40">
     <label for="username" class="hasTip" title="<?php echo JText::_('RESET_PASSWORD_USERNAME_TIP_TITLE'); ?>::<?php echo JText::_('RESET_PASSWORD_USERNAME_TIP_TEXT'); ?>"><?php echo JText::_('User Name'); ?>:   </label>
  </td>
  <td> 
       <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="required" size="36" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

For more information Check this [Why do you get a Token Error when you confirm a password reset?](http://docs.joomla.org/Confirm_password_in_1.5.16)